# Spyder - An Error Occurred While Starting the Kernel

Tags: python, spyder

I am getting the :

> An Error Occurred While Starting the Kernel

I ran :

```
pip install spyder‑kernels==2.1.*
```

in my working environment as recommended.
I am not using the default python interpreter, but a custom one.
I think this is the problem because when I switch back to the default interpreter everything is fine.
How do I make the kernel/console work with my selected python interpreter?
Thanks!

Comment: Try creating a new virtual environment.

Comment: I tried.  It doesn't matter what virtual environment I activate, installing spyder-kernels always installs to the location of the default interpreter.